# Is it possible to import Exchange settings?

Tags: powershell, csv, import, exchange-server

I want to be able to export Exchange settings which happen to be message size-related, and import them using PowerShell.

**"Backing up is good, restoring is better."**

I've been exporting them like so:

```
get-transportconfig | select maxsendsize | Export-Csv $backupPath\transportconfig.csv
get-sendconnector | select name, maxmessagesize | Export-Csv $backupPath\sendconnector.csv
get-mailbox | select Name, Maxsendsize |Export-Csv $backupPath\mailbox.csv
```

But can I do anything with this?

How does one import the settings?

You can find a lot of examples of how to import table data, but I can't find anything about importing settings.

Comment: @JPBlanc Thank you again for your insights. I've used your guidance to import three of the four properties that I want - the difference is that TransportConfig and SendConnector (x2) have a one-to-one relationship between the variable and its value. But the MaxSendSize column in the array has a value for each mailbox. I'm using:

`$mailboxbackup = Import-clixml $backupPath\mailbox.xml`
`$mailbox = Get-mailbox $mailboxbackup.name`
`foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxbackup) {set-mailbox -identity $mailbox.identity -maxsendsize $mailboxbackup.maxsendsize.value}`

but getting "cannot convert null..."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Export-Clixml` to save the  object :`enter code here`

```
Get-TransportConfig  | Export-Clixml "c:\temp\TransportConfig.xml"
$transportbackup = Import-Clixml "c:\temp\TransportConfig.xml"
Set-TransportConfig -MaxSendSize $transportbackup.MaxSendSize.Value
```

Then `Set-TransportConfig` allow you to restore the needed values.

I imagine, it's the same for `Set-SendConnector` and `Set-Mailbox`.

---

Edited

You can find more information for [Set-SendConnector](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998294%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629503%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)

You can find more information for [Set-Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123981%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) [here](http://exchangepedia.com/stuff/exquick.html)

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about export-clixml. I'll try it and report back.

Comment: What is the syntax for importing?  I'm exporting this way:  

`get-transportconfig | select maxsendsize | Export-CliXML $backupPath\transportconfig.xml`

attempting to import this way:  

`$transportbackup = import-clixml $backupPath\transportconfig.xml
set-transportconfig $transportbackup`

more to follow...

Comment: ...and getting this in response: 

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter". + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindin...mationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-Mailbox

Comment: Be carreful, the Select-object CmdLet change the type of the object itself. If you want to import just one property, you should use explicitely import this property. I edit my answer to give an example.

Comment: Fantastic, and thank you! "Set-TransportConfig -MaxSendSize $transportbackup.MaxSendSize.Value" imports the way I want it to! Can you refer me to a resource that has more information about the syntax for other properties (e.g., set-mailbox and set-sendconnector)?

Comment: I edit my answer this way, you can still use `export-clixml`.

Comment: Just to wrap this up, I found an answer to my final issue here: [link]http://ficility.net/tag/import-clixml `$mailboxes = Import-Clixml -Path "D:\mailboxes.xml"
foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes){
    Set-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox.Identity -EmailAddresses $mailbox.EmailAddresses -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $mailbox.EmailAddressPolicyEnabled
}`

Comment: You should add this as an answer, and put it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to wrap this up, I found an answer to my final issue here: [link]ficility.net/tag/import-clixml $mailboxes = Import-Clixml -Path "D:\mailboxes.xml" foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes){     Set-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox.Identity -EmailAddresses $mailbox.EmailAddresses -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $mailbox.EmailAddressPolicyEnabled }